# API working only in one condition - using laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

I am creating API my controller code:

```
public function isUserGroup(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('id');
    $isGroup = $request->input('isGroup');

    if($isGroup == false)
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('user_basic_info','users.id','=','user_basic_info.user_id')
            ->select('users.id','user_basic_info.first_name as name')
            ->where('users.id',$id)->get();
        $resultArray['users'] = $users;
    }

    if ($isGroup == true)
    {
        $groups = DB::table('group')   // Only this is working
            ->select('group.id','group.name')
            ->where('group.id',$id)->get();
        $resultArray['group'] = $groups;
        return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
    }
}
```

Now here it's returning only the group detail; either I put condition isGroup false or true, it's only returning the groups details. I don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: Try cast the input to a bool, if( (bool) $isGroup ) ..

Comment: can you show using edit into code

Comment: `dd($isGroup = $request->input('isGroup');)` debug on both the condition and see if you are getting desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly change `isGroup` to:

```
$isGroup = $request->input('isGroup') ? true : false;
```

then change `==` to `===`, and you have other something wrong with the code. Should be like this:

```
if($isGroup === false)
{
    $users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_basic_info','users.id','=','user_basic_info.user_id')
        ->select('users.id','user_basic_info.first_name as name')
        ->where('users.id',$id)->get();
    $resultArray['users'] = $users;
}else if ($isGroup === true)
{
    $groups = DB::table('group')   // Only this is working
        ->select('group.id','group.name')
        ->where('group.id',$id)->get();
    $resultArray['group'] = $groups;
}
    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
```

if still not working maybe your input of `isGroup` is wrong, if the input is a string of 'false' will return true. So if you want return users you should empty the isGroup input.

the alternative if your input is a string is below:

```
 $isGroup = $request->input('isGroup');
    if($isGroup == 'false')
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('user_basic_info','users.id','=','user_basic_info.user_id')
            ->select('users.id','user_basic_info.first_name as name')
            ->where('users.id',$id)->get();
        $resultArray['users'] = $users;
    }else if ($isGroup == 'true')
    {
        $groups = DB::table('group')   // Only this is working
            ->select('group.id','group.name')
            ->where('group.id',$id)->get();
        $resultArray['group'] = $groups;
    }
        return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line like this:

```
$isGroup = $request->input('isGroup') ? true : false;
```

Comment: This can also be achieve using `$isGroup = !! $request->input('isGroup');`

Comment: i used both above but still same response its returning the group details

Comment: its not returning the DB::table('users') query

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the type of data.

Try :

```
$isGroup = $request->input('isGroup');
var_dump($isGroup); // this will tell you type of data.
```

Once you are sure with the type, you can proceed further.